# How to get PNG as byte[] using ResourceManager with C#

Tags: c#, png, arrays, resourcemanager

I imported a PNG file into Visual Studio 2013.  A MIME mail library we're using adds visuals to HTML mail with a function that expects a byte array parameter. How to get the object returned by ResourceManager into a byte array?

```
ResourceManager rm;
rm = new ResourceManager("Foo.Properties.Resources", typeof(MYFORM).Assembly);
var obj = rm.GetObject("Logo");
```

When I try to use the `.GetStream` method, error says the object is not a stream, and to use `.GetObject` instead.

Comment: The PNG resource gets embedded as an `Image` object instead.  If you want to whack that to a byte[] then you have to use Image.Save() to a MemoryStream.  Or rename the file before you add it as a resource so VS doesn't know that it is an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GetObject will return a System.Drawing.Image object if the file is an Image

```
Image img = (Image)rm.GetObject("Logo")
```

With the Image object you can directly save it to any System.IO.Stream object

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Now you can make a copy of the bytes with the Stream.ToArray

```
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Or save it directly to a file

```
img.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/testImage.jpg")
```

Dont forget to close any used stream

```
Stream.Close();
```